# Proof of Polya Gamma Laplace Transformation

Tags: statistics, laplace-transform, statistical-inference, bayesian, logistic-regression

If $w$ follows a Polya-Gamma Distribution, denoted as $w\sim PG(b,0)$ with $b>0$ then

$$w\overset{D}{=}\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{g_{k}}{(k-1/2)^{2}},$$

where $g_{k}\sim\Gamma(b,1)$ mutually independent.

In the following paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0310, at page 4, equation (3) they derive that the Laplace Transformation of $w$ is the following

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-wt}]=\prod_{i=1}^{t}(1+\frac{t}{2\pi^{2}(k-1/2)^{2}})^{-b}=\frac{1}{\cosh^{b}(\sqrt{t/2})},$$

where in the last equality they used the  Weierstrass Factorization Theorem.

Does anyone know why the product appears in the Laplace Transformation, and overall how they derived the Laplace form??

---

I made an attempt which seems to be close to what they derived.

First, I define as $c_{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}(k-1/2)^{2}}$. Hence, the Laplace Transformation can be expressed as

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-wt}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_{k}g_{k}}]$$ because $g_{k}$ are mutually independet I can write

$$=\mathbb{E}[e^{-c_{1}g_{1}}]\mathbb{E}[e^{-c_{2}g_{2}}]...\mathbb{E}[e^{-c_{k}g_{k}}]...=(1+c_{1}t)^{-b}(1+c_{2}t)^{-b}...(1+c_{k}t)^{-b}...=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1+c_{i}t)^{-b}$$

So, should I assume that they just truncate the infinite product to only $t$ products, and if that's the case what's the reason behind that?

Comment: You can consider the Laplace transformation a moment-generating function of $-w$, and the product follows the independence.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea Yea I just edited that. By what is the reason behind the truncated product?

Comment: I agree on your opinion that they have just truncated it with no further informtion or there's a misprint since $t$ is not always an integer.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea Later in the paper the take the infinite product, so who knows. Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the idea of using the moment generating function for the $PG(1,0)$ case:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E\left(\exp(-wt)\right) &= \prod_{k=1}^\infty E\left(\exp\left(-\dfrac{t\cdot g_k}{2\pi^2(k-1/2)^2}\right)\right)\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{t}{2\pi^2(k-1/2)^2}\right)} \quad \leftarrow \text{by moment generating function}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\cosh\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{t}{2}}\right)} \quad \quad \leftarrow \text{by Weierstrass factorization of cosh}
\end{aligned}
$$

For the Weierstrass factorization of cosh, please see this link: https://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Weierstrass_factorization_of_cosh

You will find $PG(b,0)$ is quite similar, which gives the result as you provided.